# Telerik kendo-ui vs RadControls

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

With speed/performance being the ultimate goal which would you choose and why?

ASP.Net Web Forms with Telerik RadControls or ASP.Net MVC with Telerik Kendo-UI

We mainly need a hierarchical grid that can do inline updates.  We are replacing a desktop app written in Powerbuilder and the users are used to a very responsive app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote with two hands for KendoUI.

The widgets are designed to be really fast more responsive. The framework is not tighten to a server-side technology which means soon you will be able to bind a Grid to a WebAPI controller or a regular controller or you can even bind to to a service if you declare your widget with JavaScript.

There are framework features such as MVVM, Validation, Drag*n*Drop, Templates which allow you to customize your Views to the max.

It is a new product with great potential. You will see that the Ajax controls have more built in functionality (cause they are older) but almost all of them could be achieved though the flexible Kendo framework features. If you want to be up to date go for KendoUI - the widgets that Ajax controls have will sooner or later be added to the KendoUI too.

Comment: Have you used it with SignalR?

Comment: I haven't used it with SignalR sorry.